# Missing year in bibliography entry

Tags: bibtex

The publisher and year for one of the book entries in my bibliography don't show up when I compile.  What is wrong?  Here is what I have:

```
@book{Gray1999,
    author  ={Alfred Gray},
    title  = {Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica},
    edition = {2nd}.
    publisher = {CRC Press},
    year = {1999},
}

@book{Stewart2008,
    author    = {James Stewart},
    title     = {Calculus: Early Transcendentals},
    edition = {6th},
    publisher      = {Thompson Brooks/Cole},
    year      = {2008},
 }
```

The Stewart book compiles correctly, but the Gray book does not.

Comment: I see a point instead of a comma after edition in the Gray book, might that cause the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a small typing error (a period instead of a comma)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that.  But it still doesn't work.  I corrected the BibTex file, saved, and recompiled. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Maybe you have also to delete the old auxilliary files that earlier compilations produced. The ones not called *.tex or *.bib.

Comment: Please don't vote below -1. A net score of -1 is enough to signal to the asker that the question needs improvement. Lower scores should be reserved for questions that are clearly spam or malicious. Also, if you're the first to downvote, please leave a comment explaining how the question can be improved, and don't forget to come back and revert your downvote once the question has been improved.

Comment: No need for a downvote here- a reasonable question, and we've all been there (and go there!). Welcome to the group :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a **.** instead of a **,** just before **publisher =** in the Gray book.
Maybe this is causing the problem?